# One or more placement constraints on the service are undefined on all nodes that are currently up

Tags: azure-service-fabric

trying to setup that specific services get deploy to specific node types I am getting this error using Visual Studio publish dialog (that breaks calling new-servicefabricapplication PS command)

I am using the service manifest to define the placementConstraints like this:

```
<StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="VisualObjects2.WebServiceType" >
  <PlacementConstraints>(nodeType==node2)</PlacementConstraints>
</StatelessServiceType>
```

How can i define this placement constraints on the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure portal, go to your SF Cluster, select node types and for each one you can add a key-value list of placement constraints. There I put the key-value: nodetype = node2. After this, the deployment was done only in the nodes with this attribute